# How to retrieve Android Sqlite database in Arraylist

Tags: android, sqlite, arraylist, android-recyclerview

I have following code & want all the data in arraylist comes from sqlite database

```
import android.app.Activity;

public DataSingleton()  {
    visibleSections = new ArrayList<>();
    visibleSections.add("Who We Are");
    visibleSections.add("What We Do");
    visibleSections.add("How Can You Help");
   visibleSections.add("Take a Look");
   visibleSections.add("In The News");
   visibleSections.add("Get In Touch");
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you post proper code here?

Comment: i am beginner and want to change all hard code comes from database but not khow how is possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Create one model in that model generate getter and setter method of required variable.

`public static String query_select_all = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLENAME;`

```
public ArrayList<model> DataSingleton()
 {
ArrayList<visible_Model> visibleSections  = new  ArrayList<visible_Model>();


    Cursor cursor = database_helper.rawQuery(query_select_all, null);

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            visible_Model model = new visible_Model();

            model.setMessage(cursor.getString(cursor
                    .getColumnIndex(COLUMN_FROM_MSG)));

            visibleSections.add(model);

        } while (cursor.moveToNext());

    }
    return visibleSections;
}
```

Here,In above I create model name as a visile_model and use setMessage method.at last I add that model into arraylist 
    visibleSections